# Rails hStore postgresql activerecord database query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I want to be able to query an hStore column on PG database and return ONLY the values corresponding to a specific key.

The data looks like this: (keep in mind the `:data` is a postgresql `hStore`)

```
[ id: 2, data: {"tags"=>"Ruby, Objects", "type"=>"video", "title"=>"RubyTapas: Blocks, Procs, and Lambdas"}, 
  id: 3, data: {"tags"=>"JavaScript, Objects", "type"=>"video", "title"=>"RubyTapas: Blocks, Procs, and Lambdas"} ]
```

I want to do something to the effect of this:

```
Model.uniq.pluck(:tags)
```

And the output I expect is:

```
Ruby, Objects, JavaScript
```

*I am strictly trying to implement this with activerecord and postgresql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get my desired result successfully by doing:

```
Model.pluck(:data).map{|j| j['tags'].split(',') }.flatten.uniq
```

*I am still interested in a solution which doesn't require to `map` over an activerecord relation. Please advise.*

Answer (score 0):

Via [Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/episodes/345-hstore)

You can define a class eval that gives you access to the values:

```
 class Thing
      self.class_eval do
           %w[tags type title].each do |key|
           scope "has_#{key}", lambda { |value| where("payload @> hstore(?, ?)", key,           value) }

           define_method(key) do
                payload && payload[key]
           end

           define_method("#{key}=") do |value|
                self.payload = (payload || {}).merge(key => value)
           end
      end
 end
```

Now you can use

```
 t = Thing.find(2)
 t.type      <-"video"
```

Since pluck returns an array of field values, this should work (although I haven't tested it).